# Is it cheaper to select the parts or buy a pre-build Gaming PC

Tags: pc, gaming-accessories

I'm saving up for a Gaming PC for work and need it kind of fast. They hired me but said I needed to get a Gaming PC ASAP. There are 2 things I am thinking of and was wondering what one was cheaper. (I'm buying from NewEgg BTW)

- Select the parts and monitor I want and pay an extra $100 for them to build it for me
- Or, I could buy a pre-built one so I don't have to pay the extra $100 for them to build it for me

What one is cheaper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very difficult to answer without knowing at least what build you want and where you live. But usually buying parts should be cheaper(and you don't need that $500 casing, a simple one for $100 would be (almost) just as good)

The only thing you can do is find a pre-built system that you'd like and then sum up the prices all of it's components together and see for yourself.

Also, don't forget that a pre-built systems are usually immediately available, where as ordering parts may slow you down due to availability.

Comment: Thanks, i'll accept ASAP the button isnt working!